# (lib64_libmingwex_a-dirent.o):(.text+0x2bc): undefined reference to `__strcpy_chk'

Tags: linux, cygwin, mingw-w64, binutils

I'm trying to build the cygwin toolchain for Linux but When compiling Binutils I got this error.

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/../lib/libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-dirent.o):(.text+0x2bc): undefined reference to `__strcpy_chk'

I'm using github actions.

Here's what I'm working with.

Docker Container: Fedora:latest

Build = x86_64-linux-gnu

Host = x86_64-w64-mingw32

Target = x86_64-pc-cygwin

Since fedora Linux has the dependencies the toolchain needs.

Here's the configure script:

```
BINUTILS_V = 2.41

INSTALL_PATH = 

../"binutils-$BINUTILS_V"/configure \
    --quiet \
    --prefix="$INSTALL_PATH" \
    --disable-gdb \
    --build=x86_64-linux-gnu \
    --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 \
    --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin \
    --disable-libdecnumber \
    --disable-readline \
    --disable-sim \
    --enable-64-bit-bfd \
    --enable-install-libiberty \
    --enable-targets=x86_64-pc-cygwin,i686-pc-cygwin \
    --with-gcc-major-version-only \
    --disable-shared \
    --disable-host-shared \
    lt_cv_deplibs_check_method=pass_all
```